# Easy way to process search results before displaying

Tags: php, search, hierarchical, child-pages, optimization

I've got several search forms on my site and I want them to show different results. My website has a very strict hierarchy and the search form on a parent site should only show results from it's child pages.

My plan was to include different hidden fields on the different parent pages which contain the id of that particular page. In the `search.php` I then wanted to process the results and filter out the pages and posts that have no relation to the parent page.

Is there an easy way on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**

---

This is my `search.php`

```
<?php 
if (have_posts()){
  while(have_posts()){
    the_post(); ?>
    <div>
      <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
      <p><?php echo get_the_author(); ?> - <?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
      <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
  }
} else{ ?>
  <h3>Sorry</h3>
  <p>We are sorry but we could not find any matching articles on our site. Please try again with an other search request.</p>
  <?php
    get_search_form ();
}
?>
```

And the `searchform.php`:

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
  <label>Search...</label>
  <input type="text" name="s" id="s" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" placeholder="Search..." />
  <input type="hidden" name="post_parent" value="<?php echo (int)get_the_ID(); ?>" />
  <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</form>
```

**EDIT 2**

I also added `<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>` before the `if(have_posts()){}`. This results in no change. The pages are still shown.

Comment: You should only use `wp_reset_query` to clean up after `query_posts` calls, I recommend avoiding both

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pre_get_posts` filter to filter out what you need. There's an example on how to do this in Codex:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Exclude_Pages_from_Search_Results

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'post');
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

Also, [this](http://www.billerickson.net/wordpress-search-post-type/) article might get you in the direction of editing the search form...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't get the idea, on how to use this for my problem.
How do I exclude every post except the ones that have a relation to the site of the search form?

Comment: You should pass the ID of the parent post to the search, than search for the post children, and than do `$query->set('post__in', $children_ids);`, where $children_ids is an array containing the ID's you're looking for..

Comment: This also affects the normal catching of the posts... How do I delimit this to search requests from users?

Comment: In the code example I posted there's `if ($query->is_search)` - that limits anything you do inside to just the search queries...

Comment: This is a response to **user1049961** <hr> Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunately, I don't really get it working... I included this code to my `functions.php`and tested it out. There are still results shown which have a different parent. $children_ids = get_children( $args ); $args = array( 'post_parent' => $_GET['pageID'], 'post_type' => 'any', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => 'publish' ); function search_filter($query) { if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) { if ( $query->is_search() ) { $query->set('post__in', $children_ids); } } } add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter')

Comment: You don't need the additional `get_children` query, just set `post_parent` in the filter

Comment: This isn't an answer. To clarify your question, please use the edit link below your question and add additional code there.

Answer (score 0):

While the `pre_get_posts` filter is going to let you modify the main query before it happens, letting you add extra requirements, in this case it isn't necessary! You can do it all with the URL and the search form

First, the query variables passed into `WP_Query` can be used in the URL. `post_parent` being the query var you're wanting.

So if we have this:

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="s" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_parent" value="<?php echo (int)get_the_ID(); ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="page"/>
</form>
```

Then any search results will be limited to those whose post_parent is the page that the search came from. You'll see URLs such as `/?s=test&post_parent=123`.

This trick can be used to filter by categories and authors, for example, searching a category:

`/category/example/?s=test`

Only showing posts by a particular author in a date archive:

`/2016/?author=123`

Comment: I just implemented your code snippet, but it does not work. I still get sites from different parents.

Comment: Do you replace or modify the main query/loop in your `search.php`? Any signs of `query_posts` or `WP_Query`? If you have enough subpages that you need to search them, perhaps you should be using a custom post type or a custom taxonomy instead of hacking things into parent and child pages

Comment: No, I don't think so. I added an edit to the question which shows the `search.php` as well as the `searchform.php`.

Comment: @Chwebo I realise now, you're searching inside pages not posts, I've added a `post_type` field. Keep in mind that none of these solutions will handle sub-sub-pages, and grandchild pages, if you want those then your search query is going to become significantly slower/more expensive, and the code will become a lot more complex and difficult

Comment: Well... I do want to include **all** the pages. My hierarchy is like the following: Parent Page 1 - Parent  Page 2 - Parent  Page 3 - Content Page. Is there a plugin to achieve this or is it extremely hard to hand-code it by myself?

Comment: I'm not aware of a plugin, but you should expect very slow searches if you do, the kind that might fail to finish on shared hosting, or at least get you in trouble with your host. What exactly is this content? Custom post types and taxonomies could make this a lot more manageable

Comment: It's a website about chemistry. The top level parent page would be something like _Practical courses_ followed by some fields of chemistry where practical courses are offered, like _Inorganic chemistry_, _Organic chemistry_ and so on. These pages have subpages too. These will be the different practical courses of that particular field. Ex: _Quantitative analytics_. These pages contain the content pages (the different methods of that course)

Comment: So what I want to accomplish is, that the visitor can search on, say the _Practical courses_-site, and only get results that are related to practical courses. If he searches on the _Inorganic chemistry_-page he should only get results that are related to practical courses of inorganic chemistry. I think you get the idea. If I would try to accomplish this with custom post types, I'd have to create a post type for each sub-page. This would be extremely unorganized in the backend...

Comment: You'd only need to create a single post type: `course`. You'd then need a single taxonomy `course-category`. "Inorganic chemistry" would be a top level course category, etc and they'd use `single-course.php` and `taxonomy-course-category.php`, searching would use the same trick as in my answer, only taxonomies are built for filtering, page parents aren't

Comment: That's a great idea. Sorry, I had no idea of the powers of custom post types and taxonomies... Thanks a lot!

Comment: Going back to your original problem if you did that, you would specify the term/course category you want to search through

Comment: I've set it all up now and I wonder how I can get a page that displays all the different taxonomy categories... Inside the _Practical courses_ post-type I've got five categories which represent the different courses. These have child categories for the contents of that course. So on the www.domain.com/practical-courses page, I want to display all the parent categories and inside, say the _Qualitative Analysis_ child-category all the sub-categories should be returned.

Comment: That sounds like a good question, better to start a new one that cram it all into comments